# Query Nested Object properties against multiple values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have nested object comment with two properties tag and group. If I do below query then it gives me the desired result.

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "match": {
                  "comment.tag": {
                    "query": "SPRING",
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              },
              "must_not": {
                "match": {
                  "comment.group": {
                    "query": "ABC",
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "comment"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I execute below query then it doesn't give me the desired result.

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "match": {
                  "comment.tag": {
                    "query": [
                      "SPRING",
                      "HIBERNATE"
                    ],
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              },
              "must_not": {
                "match": {
                  "comment.group": {
                    "query": [
                      "ABC",
                      "XYZ"
                    ],
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "comment"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The difference between these two is that I am querying both properties of nested object against multiple values.

With second query it just picks up the last values in the list provided to search and returns the result.

Is there a way to write query where I can specify pass list of values and  all values are included in search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with being a nested query/filter. Instead, it's how you are using the [`match` query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). It does not expect an array of values.

There are really two ways to achieve what you appear to be trying. Before going into them, I did want to note that the `match` query defaults to using the `boolean` type, so you can leave that out.

1. You can change the `match` query to simply supply both values in the string. Order is irrelevant:

   ```
   "bool" : {
     "must" : {
       "match" : {
         "comment.tag" : "SPRING HIBERNATE"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   The reason that this works is because the field will use the search analyzer to tokenize the string in the same way that the field is indexed (by default). As a result, assuming a default string analyzer, you will end up searching for `spring` *or* `hibernate`. Because you are not using phrase matching, order is truly irrelevant.
2. The other way is to explicitly separate them using the outer `bool`/`must` query (the same applies to the `must_not` and `should`). Since you want them treated like `OR`s, you need to use `should` instead of `must` this way:

   ```
   "bool" : {
     "should" : [
       {
         "match" : { "company.tag" : "SPRING" }
       },
       {
         "match" : { "company.tag" : "HIBERNATE" }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Note: If you also include a `must`, then you need to set `minimum_should_match` to 1 (inside of the `bool` object) so that it does not become optional. Without the `must` and `must_not`, it is implicitly 1.

Comment: First solution does work but the second one did not work. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Oh, woops. The second one should be `should` in place of `must` so that it is treated like an `or` instead of `and`.